# Saving Long and Latitude to String - Parsing String to Google Maps

Tags: android, string, url, gps, location

I'm trying to do the following.

-Get the long and latitude stored as a String that I can

-Insert into a clickable URL that opens Google Maps (ie http://maps.google.com/long=string1+lat=string2) - this URL is included in an email that is being sent through the default email app.

I've tried looking at URI, Linkify, Reverse GeoCoding but I can't seem to get anything. I can get the co-ords and display as a Toast notification, but trying to save them to use elsewhere is problematic at the moment.

I've string String lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude) but didn't get anything from it, or maybe there was no co-ords to get at the time the code executed as it perhaps didn't have a GPS lock, not too sure. Please see code below.

public class ConfirmScreen extends Activity{

```
String mapCoord = "http://maps.google.com";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_screen);


    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, mLocListener);

    sendEmail();
    playSound();
}

public void backHome(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Method to start playing and looping a sound.

public void playSound()
{
    MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.warning);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean soundCheck = sp.getBoolean("SOUND", false);
    if (soundCheck)
    {
        clickSound.start();
    }

}// method end

public void sendEmail()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String nameValue = sp.getString("NAME", "failed to get name");
    String emailValue = sp.getString("EMAIL", "failed to get email");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailValue});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email sent from DON'T PANIC - A Chris O'Brien Project");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there\n" + nameValue + " is in mortal danger. Please see the co-ords attached and run to their rescue!" +
            " If you don't see any co-ords, they didn't check the box and assume you know where they are.\nKind Regards\nDon't Panic! \n\n" +  mapCoord);

    try
    {   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...."));
    } 
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){

        Toast.makeText(ConfirmScreen.this, "There are no email clients installed or set up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Location Listener
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        String text = "Current Location is \nLat: " + location.getLatitude() + " \nLng: " + location.getLongitude();
        //mapCoord =  Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + " " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_confirm_screen, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set mapCoord to `"http://maps.google.com"`. Then this is added to the text of your email. I also noticed that you've commented out this line in `onLocationChanged()`:

```
//mapCoord =  Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + " " +
                  Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
```

You can get the user's coordinates that way, but the problem is that location update callbacks are asynchronous. When you call

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, mLocListener);
```

this just registers your `MyLocationListener` to receive callbacks. It doesn't actually generate a callback until the user's position changes. But you don't wait for that. You send the email right away. In most cases the location will be empty because your callback has not yet been called back.

You can try to use `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` (which returns right away with the last known location) but in my experience it often returns null.

You can also register for updates, put up a progress dialog telling the user "detecting your location..." and wait until `onLocationChanged()` gets called back.